# jquery .map() div that has certain class

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

i'm trying to filter product price based on visible div set by isotope js.I tried these codes,but it gives null on console.log.Please kindly point me where is the mistake.Thanks a lot.

```
<div class=".product-layout">
  <div id="item" class=".mix-item isotope-item">
    <div class=".product" data-price="29"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="item" class=".mix-item isotope-item isotope-hidden">
    <div class=".product" data-price="29"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="item" class=".mix-item isotope-item isotope-hidden">
    <div class=".product" data-price="29"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="item" class=".mix-item isotope-item">
    <div class=".product" data-price="29"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> 

```
var numbers = $("#item).not(".isotope-hidden").map(function () {
       return parseInt(this.children(".product").getAttribute('data-price'), 10) || -Infinity;
   }).toArray();
Console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: where is your js code?

Comment: Both links were to the same location. Could you plz post your js code here.

Comment: You are missing quote and id shoud be unique.

Comment: @C-linkNepal which quote do you mean?Thanks

Comment: @C-linkNepal Thanks for reminding me.Is it possible to use class instead of id to map?And is the code correct?Thanks

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks for reminding me to drop the dot for class name.I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your html in this way. Give a class and not an id to your elements

```
<div class=".product-layout">
      <div class="item" class=".mix-item isotope-item">
        <div class=".product" data-price="29"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" class=".mix-item isotope-item isotope-hidden">
        <div class=".product" data-price="29"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" class=".mix-item isotope-item isotope-hidden">
        <div class=".product" data-price="29"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" class=".mix-item isotope-item">
        <div class=".product" data-price="29"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and then in your jquery code use class selector `.` and not id selector `#`

```
var numbers = $(".item:not(.isotope-hidden)").map(function () {
       return parseInt($(this).children(".product").attr('data-price'), 10) || Infinity;
   }).toArray();
```

note that I have changed jquery not mehod (`.not()`) with not selector (`:not`) because of performance

for documentation refer [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,i'll try it first.I'll let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ID should be unique, thus you should change those id with class and now do like this:

```
var numbers = $(".item").not(".isotope-hidden").map(function () {
       return parseInt($(this).children(".product").data('price'), 10) || Infinity;
   }).toArray();
console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: I'll try it and i will let you know the result.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some issues. First don't start class by "." ( class=".product" ). And I made some changes, try this.

```
    var numbers = $(".item").not(".isotope-hidden").map(function () {
       return parseInt($($(this).children(".product")[0]).attr("data-price"), 10) || Infinity;
   }).toArray();
console.log(numbers);
```

---

```
<div class="product-layout">
  <div class=".mix-item isotope-item item">
    <div class="product" data-price="29"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="item" class=".mix-item isotope-item isotope-hidden item">
    <div class="product" data-price="29"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="item" class=".mix-item isotope-item isotope-hidden item">
    <div class="product" data-price="29"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="item" class=".mix-item isotope-item item">
    <div class="product" data-price="29"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```